# Equation of all planes passing through the given line?

Tags: vectors

We are given a line $\overrightarrow r = \lambda(\hat i-\hat j+\hat k) $ which is the intersection of planes $ x+y=0$ and $y+z=0$.

How do I find the equation all planes passing through $ \overrightarrow r$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha(x+y)+\beta(y+z)=0$, $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha^2+\beta^2\ne0$

Comment: Can you please explain how do we get that?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. I think instead of $\alpha$ it will be just 1. Thanks.

Comment: $\alpha(x+y)+\beta(y+z)=0$ incldues all planes passing through $\vec{r}$ except $y+z=0$.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thanks

Comment: @amd Just amended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @CYAries Sir why you wrote that condition on alpha , beta. They dont need any condition at all isnt ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax $\alpha^2+\beta^2\ne=0$ just means that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not both zero.  If $\alpha=\beta=0$, the equation becomes $0=0$ and is not a plane.

Comment: I see thanks Sir  , is there a way to get the family of plane from just a **given line equation** ? @CYAries